# Can someone help me understand this piece of code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, currying

```
var curryIt = function(uncurried) {
  var parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    return uncurried.apply(this, parameters.concat(
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
    ));
  };
};
var greeter = function(greeting, separator, emphasis, name) {
  console.log(greeting + separator + name + emphasis);
};
var greetHello = curryIt(greeter, "Hello", ", ", ".");
greetHello("Heidi"); //"Hello, Heidi."
greetHello("Eddie"); //"Hello, Eddie."
```

I get the overall picture of what is happening but I do not understand what is being carried out in the curryIt function.

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: read a tutorial on `Function.bind()` and it will make sense, since bind is well-documented and performs a curry much like the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Every function has an object called `arguments`, which contains in an array like data structure the arguments which the *caller* of the function uses.

For example, let that we have the following function:

```
function sum(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

If we call `sum` as below:

```
sum(3,4)
```

the `arguments` would contain two items 3 and 4. (Actually, you could call `sum` with 3, 4 or more arguments. All these values would be contained in the arguments).

The *key word* in the above statement is the *array like data structure*. `arguments` is not an array. So you can't have available the Array's methods (push, shift, slice, etc.)

**What does `slice`?**

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

For further info please have a look here.

> So if you want to `apply` slice on `arguments` would could you do?

Since `arguments` is not an array, (`arguments instanceof Array` returns false), you can't do so like below:

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
var sliced = a.slice(1,3);
```

But you can't do it like below:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

**What does call?**

> The call() method calls a function **with a given this** value and
>   arguments provided individually.

For further info please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

So, essentially, the following line of code

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

calls the function called `slice` on the `arguments` objects passing 1 as it's argument. So you get an array with all the arguments except the first.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about a functional programming paradigm called Currying. It's all about saving one or more arguments into a returned function to be re used at a later time. It's highly related with the closures topic of JavaScript.

Let's refactor the code in a more functional manner.

```js
var curryIt = (uncurried,...args) => name => uncurried(...args,name),
    greeter = (greeting, separator, emphasis, name) => console.log(greeting + separator + name + emphasis),
 greetHello = curryIt(greeter, "Hello", ", ", ".");
 
greetHello("Heidi"); //"Hello, Heidi."
greetHello("Eddie"); //"Hello, Eddie."
```

`curryIt` function takes several argument of which the first one is a function called `uncurried` the rest of the argument are collected in the `args` array by the help of the rest operator (`...`) of ES6.

Then we return a function which takes a single argument called `name` and makes use of the parameters passed to it's parent function by `args` array. So, right now the `args` array and it's elements are under closure. The returned function will invoke the passed `uncurried` function by providing the available arguments in a proper order.